# Sharing token among multiple websites to prevent logins in each websites

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, session, token

Let us consider I have 2 websites A & B. Now I have logged into A using my credentials & a token has been generated. I have stored the token & Client IP along with the token's expiry into the DB. Now there is a button inside A which will redirect me to B. I want B to be authenticated with the same token so that I don't have to manually log into B.

Also I cannot skip the login page of B  every time as one might directly log into B (without A) at that time login is required .

So how can I get the token once B is launched only via A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to implement SSO (Single Sign-On) flow. Let's say we have two sites "site-a.com" and "site-b.com". There multiple ways we could go about building SSO, the easiest would be to have a shared "gateway point" (let's call it "sso-site.com") that implements the following flow:

- The user comes to site A
- They get redirected to the SSO gateway
- SSO gateway checks for the token. If found, it redirects the user back to the site A. If the user needs to login, they are redirected to the login page and then back to the site A.
- Any link to site B will put the user through the same "gateway" (same authentication flow as above)

There are multiple ways the gateway could control the flow between sites, it all depends on the business logic you are building. The key part here is that the site navigation is forced through a central gateway that makes sure that the users who should log in are logged in and do so only once.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there is any way that I send the token as a query parameter while redirection from A to B. And in the B I can log via the same token ?

Comment: Yes you can BUT... Query params are easily detected and spoofed so that any user with slightly above average skills can figure out the token and do whatever they want with it. If you still prefer to send it as a query string param, the easiest way is to attach click handler to the link and handle your own redirect logic (with extra params, headers and whatnot)

Comment: Even if the user detects the token & modify it I have re-checked the validation of the token in the redirected website (site B). So if anyone modifies it the token will become invalid. So the user won't be able to navigate through the B & hence will be redirected to B's login page